# withRouter, connect() and react-compose

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using `react-redux` connect function with `withRouter` function, and also I am trying to use `compose()` here. This is the code:

```
export default compose (
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Dashboard);
```

But I receive the next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at wrapWithConnect (connectAdvanced.js:84)
    at applyFunctor (index.js:124)
    at index.js:144
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at ComposedComponent (index.js:143)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:305
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:304)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:279)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:187)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:522)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:522)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:104)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:319)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (ReactMount.js:401)
    at Object.render (ReactMount.js:422)
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: are you doing JSON.stringify on an object in your state that is not stringify-able?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`connect` returns a function that takes the component.  So, I think it would work if you slightly change your parens:

```
export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard)
);
```

Or:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(compose(
    withRouter,
    Dashboard
));
```

Comment: `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeComponent))` is also working, but should I write it  like that?

Comment: You don't *have* to use `compose`, but as you add more and more HOCs, I think it reads better to use compose, otherwise it is hard to see where the parens are.

Comment: Yes understood. I also feel using `compose` is the better way

Comment: how about: `compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Dashboard)`, makes all flat

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use this as mentioned by `Parnab Sanya`

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeComponent))`

or If you have `withStyles()` then use this

```
export default withRouter(
compose(
   withStyles(HomeComponentStyle),

   connect(mapStateToProps)
)(HomeComponent));
```

Comment: Sahan, you saved my life! Went through like 10 threads and 10 articles and none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard))`

Works fine and is short.