# Programmatic React Router navigation with TypeScript and Redux in class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, navigation

I've spent like 3 hours total looking for right answer on how to programmatically navigate with React Router in Typescript React class component that is already connected to Redux. None of it worked, Typescript was giving all sort of type errors.

I did found only partial solution, so I am creating this thread and answering it for future usage for people who had similar issue and are still unable to find the answer.

Thanks a lot to:

- Sahan's answer here [withRouter, connect() and react-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485056/withrouter-connect-and-react-compose)
- Henrik's answer here [Programmatically navigating : React Router V4+ Typescript giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796569/programmatically-navigating-react-router-v4-typescript-giving-error)

Answer (score 0):

Below are all important core parts that allows you to connect React Router, Redux inside class component using Typescript. I hope this helped you.

```js
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../reducers/rootReducer"; // your custom file

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {return {...}}; // RootState is your main state from Redux
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {return{...}};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

type MyProps = PropsFromRedux & RouteComponentProps & {...}; // Custom props goes here

class YourReactClassComponent extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {...}

export default withRouter(connector(YourReactClassComponent));
```